# When I use bison to parse a helloworld file written in java, bison can only parse it line by line. How can I parse it in multiple lines?

Tags: c

In fact, you don’t need to look at the code, you just need to tell me how to parse a method body or class, how bison parses multiple lines of structured code, instead of parsing line by line

How do I use bison to parse the code of this file? My current technology can only parse line by line.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

bison code

```
program: /* nothing */
    | program statement EOL
        {
            printf("%g\n>> ", eval($2));
            treefree($2);
        }
    | program declare_pre EOL 
        { printf("\n>> "); }
    | program declare_class EOL
        {
            printf("\n>>");
        }

    | program EOL
        { printf(">> "); }
    | program error EOL
        {
            yyerrok;
            printf("\n>> ");
        }
;

declare_class: /* nothing */    { $$ = NULL; }
    | class_access_modifier CLASS NAME '{' list '}'
        {
            defcls($3, $5);
            printf("%g\n>> ", eval($5));
            $$ = $3;
        }
;
```

For example, the content in the file is:

```
public class test {}
```

bison can be directly parsed successfully
But if you change it into another form

```
public class test {
     void demo(int i, int j) {}
}
```

At this time, bison will report an error because there is no way to process the content after the first line'{', the rule is'{' list'}'
Cannot match one or more line breaks